# Should Moderators Names Appear on the Top Reviewer List?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

[image]

This is not me complaining, since 65 close vote reviews is awesome, but perhaps there could be a special little section for Top Moderator Reviewers of the day, seeing as they aren't limited by the 40 vote (close vote in this example) limit?

₉ᵢᵥₑ ₘₑ ₘᵧ #₁ ₛₚₒₜ ₚₗₛ

Good job Baum!

Comment: What's the exact harm though? Moderators don't have a queue limit and not all moderators perform reviews.

Comment: @Makoto absolutely no harm at all, just an idea is all

Comment: OR give us regular high rep mortals unlimited close votes and everyone can get 65 reviews in the close vote queue! (Only slightly serious)

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't notice this very often on Stack Overflow because the moderator-only queue is usually overflowing with flags, which keeps the mods occupied. The mod flag queue been under control recently, and Baum decided (with my encouragement) to spend some time tackling the overflowing close-vote queue. Moderators on other Stack Exchange sites do this often. For example, if you look at Code Review, you'll see that their mods do a lot of reviews because their mod-only flag queue volume is much lower. This is all good. You *want* mods doing this moderation stuff.

Comment: I think I may have worded myself poorly, in no way am I saying mods shouldn’t be encouraged to do queue stuff :)

Comment: So then why do you want to hide their progress?

Comment: I for one welcome the fact that a moderator would have time and muse to do something like this.

Comment: Not hide! Their own list just as visible as the normal one

Comment: I, for one, welcome our new arboreal overlords. (cc @Magisch)

Answer (score 20):

I disagree. If a moderator wants to work the queue, they should be recognized for doing so.

I for one would never discourage moderators from reviewing lots of stuff.

Comment: Implying that I am discouraging them?

Comment: @SterlingArcher No, I'm just suggesting that if a moderator was feeling particularly motivated that day and helped out a bunch in our queues they deserve the recognition of being the top reviewer. The close vote queue needs all the help that it can get.